Meaning of Prenayamo Vasudevam - shloka8 (12 verses)
I saw there was a thread where meaning of only first 6 verses of prenayamo vasudevam was posted. I am looking for the meaning of all 12 verses.
Could someone please share.

there was a thread where? what thread? is there a link to it? can you copy some information from it to here? can you please clarify this question by adding more information to it?
